# Program to check if heap order is correct or not

Tags: java, generics, heap

There is a Java program to check if a Heap (Min) is in the correct order. Heap Order means the parent is less than both left child and right child.

```
package testers;

import heap.Heap;
import java.util.List;

public class HeapTester
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Heap<Integer> heap = new Heap <>();
        heap.add(50);
        heap.add(25);
        heap.add(26);
        heap.add(15);
        heap.add(10);
        heap.add(16);
        heap.add(3);
        heap.add(7);
        heap.add(10);
        heap.add(12);
        heap.add(2);
        System.out.println(heap);
        System.out.println(hasHeapOrder(heap.copy()));
    }

    private static <T extends Comparable<T>> boolean hasHeapOrder(List<T> list)
    {
        if(list.size() < 2) return true;

        boolean hasOrder = true;

        int parent = 0;
        int leftChild = 2 * parent + 1;
        int rightChild = 2 * parent + 2;

        while(leftChild < list.size())
        {
            if(list.get(parent).compareTo(list.get(leftChild)) > 0)
            {
                hasOrder = false;
                break;
            }
            if(rightChild < list.size())
            {
            if(list.get(parent).compareTo(list.get(rightChild)) > 0)
                {
                    hasOrder = false;
                    break;
                }
            }

            parent++;
            leftChild = 2 * parent + 1;
            rightChild = 2 * parent + 2;
        }
        return hasOrder;
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Avoid flag variables if you don't need them

The `hasOrder` flag variable is unnecessary.
When you set this variable to `false`,
you could `return false` instead.
If the end of the loop is reached, you can `return true`.

#### Avoid unnecessary special handling

The special treatment for the case `list.size() < 2` is unnecessary.
The rest of the implementation handles that case naturally.

#### Don't repeat yourself

The computation logic of the left and right child indexes is duplicated twice.
You could eliminate that by changing the loop to `while (true)`, and making this computation the first step of the loop instead of last:

```
while (true) {
  int leftChild = 2 * parent + 1;
  int rightChild = 2 * parent + 2;

  if (leftChild >= list.size()) {
    break;
  }

  // ...
```

#### Test using a unit test framework

Testing by printing stuff is not very useful.
You have to read the output to verify it's correct,
which takes mental effort, and error-prone.
It's better to use a proper unit testing framework,
where test cases will give you simple yes-no answers per test case;
no need to re-interpret passing results.

#### Test all corner cases

Only one case is "tested".
You need more tests to verify that `hasHeapOrder` correctly returns `true` or `false` depending on the input.
I suppose you have an implementation of `Heap` such that `heap.copy()` returns a correctly heap-ordered list, and so `hasHeapOrder` returns `true`.
At the minimum,
you should verify that `hasHeapOrder` returns `false` for lists like 4, 1, 2 and 4, 5, 2.